# Multiple request instead of one in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have this select which I expected to be executed by sending one command to SQL Server but I can see 10s requests instead. How can I fix it?

We have Companies which have Customers and Orders. For some reasons Orders are under Company entity.

```
var q = _dbContext.Companies
        .Include(x => x.Customers)
        .Include(c => c.Orders)
        .Where(a => a.CompanyId == 123);

 var total = await q.CountAsync();

 q = q.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyCode)
     .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

 var res = await q.Select(x => new ResultDto()
 {
     CompanyCode = x.CompanyCode,     
     Customers = x.Customers
         .Where(c => c.IsActive)
         .Select(c => new CustomerDto()
         {
             FirstName = c.FirstName,
             Surname = c.Surname,             
             Orders = x.Orders
                 .Where(o => o.IsOpen)
                 .Select(o => new OrderDto()
                 {
                     DateCreated = o.DateCreated
                 }).ToList()
         }).FirstOrDefault(),
 }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: When you run `.ToList()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` this will execute the query you have entered before moving on to the outer selects

Comment: Thanks, so what is the solution?

Comment: Putting a `.ToList()` after .Take(pageSize) should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is EF.NetCore optimization. 
You actually cant achieve one query when your navigation properties are collections. 
I can't find any links right now, but this is by design.

Once you have a collection in your navigations inside select or inside includes it will produce a separate query for each root entity. The reason I believe is the redundant data amount produced by such a query.

I suggest leave it as is if you have not a lot of data < 1000 rows in a result. You will see a lot of queries but they will be really fast.

As I can see you have pagination here so it shouldn't be a problem.

Otherwise, select your collections separately and join them in memory carefully.

Unfortunately, there is no other way for EF Core

Also, I recommend to turn on EF core logs to what is going on early. I bet FirstOrDefault will produce some warning.

Comment: Thank you, if this is the case I will run separate queries and merge them manually!

Comment: This definitely is **not** "by design". `ToList` inside correlated subqueries should trigger the [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries). I haven`t checked it, but it could be a bug/defect caused by `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @IvanStoev yes this by design as by  this explanation  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12098#issuecomment-391095895

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel It's better to say it **was** "by design", since they've changed their mind and in 3.0 switched to [Single SQL statement per LINQ query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#single-sql-statement-per-linq-query). Which started causing a lot of performance issues, so I'm not sure what will be the next "design decision".